# UIImageView Recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibutton

In my app I have a big UIImageView and other 5 smaller.

My intention is to copy the content of the selected small Image to the biggest one. Also to get the name of the chosen image and show with a UILabel.

Will be maybe easier to replace the small images by UIButtons and display the image as a background?

Comment: One option is to use the image view tag property. You can also store some extra details into an array and just use the tag property (0, 1 etc) as keys for it. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add a gestureRecognizer to each imageView.  The function called by the gestureRecognizer would then change the image on the "big picker view".  There is no built-in way to get the image name that the user chose.  If you really needed this, then you could sublcass UIImageView and add a fileName property.

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bigPickerImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // create tap gesture recognizer
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapGesture:")

    // add it to the image view;
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    // make sure imageView can be interacted with by user
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true        
}

func tapGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // if the tapped view is a UIImageView then set it to imageview
    if let imageView = gesture.view as? UIImageView {  // if you subclass UIImageView, then change "UIImageView" to your subclass
        // change the image on the bigPickerImageView
        bigPickerImageView.image = imageView.image
        // if you subclass UIImageView, then you could get the filename here.
    }
}
```