# How to add an action for when an image is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, button, action

I am trying to use a custom image as a button in my app. How do I add an action for an image?

This is for an iOS app and I don't want to use the default text button as a button. I've already tried control+dragging the image to the ViewController but there is no "Action" option.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let designChoice = designPrac.randomElement()
    let forChoice = forWhatPrac.randomElement()
    let helpChoice = toHelpPrac.randomElement()

    designLabel.text = designChoice
    forLabel.text = forChoice
    helpLabel.text = helpChoice
}
```

This is the code I have to run when the app launches but I can't find a way to get this to work for when my image button is clicked.

Comment: What image? The code you posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question? Why not use `UIButton` with your image?

Comment: have you tried making a UIButton the same size on the image and just removing the "button" text?  have you tried a tap gesture on the UIImageView?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "use UIButton" with your image. I am new to Swift sorry for the ignorance. I know how to add a button to the storyboard but not how to make it the image I have in Assets.xcassets. How do I use tap gesture?

Comment: @bluewizard3 A normal UIButton can have an image instead of a title.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880607/how-to-assign-an-action-for-uiimageview-object-in-swift/53809261#53809261   ->  add tap gesture  on imageview and handle action of imageview and also we can use all the child of UIView.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add an action to an `UIImageView`, you need to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it, you can do it like this:

```
<#YourImageView#>.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleImageTap)))
```

Then you can handle the tap using the selector:

```
@objc func handleImageTap() {
    // handle image tap here    
}
```

Comment: So for this I'm guessing add an outlet for the `UIImageView` and then use its name in place of <#YourImageView#>?

Comment: Yes, don't forget to set constraints. And also placing an image on it to test will make things easier.

Comment: What do you mean by set constraints?

Comment: They're used to position components. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use addGestureRecognizer for this purpose:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
//add necessary code 
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MethodForAction)))
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [How do you make an UIImageView on the storyboard clickable (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202882/how-do-you-make-an-uiimageview-on-the-storyboard-clickable-swift):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // create tap gesture recognizer
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.imageTapped(gesture:)))

    // add it to the image view;
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    // make sure imageView can be interacted with by user
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

func imageTapped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // if the tapped view is a UIImageView then set it to imageview
    if (gesture.view as? UIImageView) != nil {
        print("Image Tapped")
        //Here you can initiate your new ViewController

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of simply copying someone else's answer, the question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think i have enough rep to mark it as a duplicate. If I do, I don't know how to do it...